# SSH tunnels with putty

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

Is this setup possible:

isp -> tunnel-1 -> tunnel-2 -> destination

tunnel-2 will be exit IP, but in the "tunnel-1" containter. So ISP should only see traffic from tunnel-1. The programs used should be putty and chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. it seems reasonable to connect a tunnel from the customer premises to the tunnel1 source interface, in which case the isp couldn't see anything at all except a single encrypted tunnel with data passing across it. they can probably tell alot from signal timeing, size, etc, but they couldn't see any data in the tunnel packet.